# C++: expected ';' at end of member declaration

Tags: c++

sorry for the French-English mix...
I'm getting [Error] expected ';' at end of member declaration for this line

***public: monthly(string n,string s,int t,int b,double sl,int nc,double tc)::employee(n,s,t,b)***

found in

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class employee {protected: string name;
                        string surname;
                        int tel;
                        int nbureau;
                public:  employee(string n,string s,int t,int b){
                    name=n;surname=s;tel=t;nbureau=b;
                }
                void affich(){
                    cout<<"nom"<<name<<"\nprenom"<<surname<<"\nnumero tel"<<tel<<"\nnumero bureau"<<nbureau;
                }
                };
class monthly: public employee {private:double salary; 
                                        int nbc;
                                        double tcom;
                                public: monthly(string n,string s,int t,int b,double sl,int nc,double tc)::employee(n,s,t,b){
                                    salary=sl;nbc=nc;tcom=tc;
                                }
                                void affich(){
                                    cout<<"nom"<<employee.name<<"\nprenom"<<employee.surname<<"\nnumero tel"<<employee.tel<<"\nnumero bureau"<<employee.nbureau<<"\nsalaire"<<salary<<"\nnombre de commissions"<<nbc<<"\ntaux de commission"<<tc;
                                }
                                double salary(){
                                    return salary+(nbc*tcom);
                                }
};
```

Comment: You should use `:` instead of `::` for member initialization list. Your program have more problems.

Comment: Your formatting is very weird. You may want to look into using clang-format manually or in your editor.

Comment: @MikeCAT thank you yes i'm looking into them one by one

Comment: print anything at every line of code and check where your code is breaking.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here is how your code should look. clang-format fixed it up.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class employee {
protected:
  string name;
  string surname;
  int tel;
  int nbureau;

public:
  employee(string n, string s, int t, int b) {
    name = n;
    surname = s;
    tel = t;
    nbureau = b;
  }
  void affich() {
    cout << "nom" << name << "\nprenom" << surname << "\nnumero tel" << tel
         << "\nnumero bureau" << nbureau;
  }
};
class monthly : public employee {
private:
  double salary;
  int nbc;
  double tcom;

public:
  monthly(string n, string s, int t, int b, double sl, int nc,
          double tc)::employee(n, s, t, b) {
    salary = sl;
    nbc = nc;
    tcom = tc;
  }
  void affich() {
    cout << "nom" << employee.name << "\nprenom" << employee.surname
         << "\nnumero tel" << employee.tel << "\nnumero bureau"
         << employee.nbureau << "\nsalaire" << salary
         << "\nnombre de commissions" << nbc << "\ntaux de commission" << tc;
  }
  double salary() { return salary + (nbc * tcom); }
};
```

And this is a version with the syntax fixed up:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class employee {
protected:
  string name;
  string surname;
  int tel;
  int nbureau;

public:
  employee(string n, string s, int t, int b)
      : name(n), surname(s), tel(t), nbureau(b) {}
  void affich() {
    cout << "nom" << name << "\nprenom" << surname << "\nnumero tel" << tel
         << "\nnumero bureau" << nbureau;
  }
};
class monthly : public employee {
private:
  double salary;
  int nbc;
  double tcom;

public:
  monthly(string n, string s, int t, int b, double sl, int nc, double tc)
      : employee(n, s, t, b), salary(sl), nbc(nc), tcom(tc) {}
  void affich() {
    cout << "nom" << name << "\nprenom" << surname << "\nnumero tel" << tel
         << "\nnumero bureau" << nbureau << "\nsalaire" << salary
         << "\nnombre de commissions" << nbc << "\ntaux de commission" << tcom;
  }
  double get_salary() { return salary + (nbc * tcom); }
};
```

Comment: Can't you just edit the question? I mean this is not really answering the question.